# What are these quoted strings in a class definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking at some Python code that has quoted strings used in a class definition in a way I hadn't seen before:

```
class Foo:
    """
    Docstring for the class. This one I understand, of
    course. I'm wondering about the two strings below.
    """

    one: str
    "One thing."
    another: str
    "Another thing."

    def __init__(self):
    # etc, etc.
```

What are those last two quoted strings for? I am guessing that the Python runtime ignores them, and there is some external tooling that uses them?

Comment: If the code used triple quotes instead of single quotes, it would be a doc string, though they are supposed to go before the variable, not after.  Its intent would be to describe the purpose of the variable.    As it is now, these strings are ignored.  You can ignore them, too.

Comment: @FrankYellin: Triple quotes have nothing to do with docstrings. Docstrings can use any form of string literal (although f-strings don't count).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica    https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/ suggests that doc strings should always be triple-quoted.   Yes, you are right that it is a suggestion, not a requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are probably for Sphinx autodoc. Python ignores them - Python itself doesn't support docstrings for attributes - but Sphinx autodoc [recognizes](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autofunction) a string literal after an attribute definition as documentation for that attribute. I think annotations probably count for this purpose, but I don't have the setup to test it.

Comment: "Python ignores them" -> strictly speaking, doesn't Python create these strings when the class definition is executed?

Comment: @snakecharmerb: Strictly speaking, they get optimized out. I don't know where that happens in the current implementation, but you can see the string isn't there in the [`dis.dis` output](https://ideone.com/dPSDyw).